# Excel - Match cells that contains exact match from list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

In my **first sheet** I have a list which contains the following 10 items in Column A (One on row: A2-A11):

```
egg
bootleggers egg
egg is good
egg and ham
eggs and hams
bootleggers
eggshells
veggie
reggae
```

I have a **second sheet** which contains a table (table name: `good_food`) with the following items:

```
egg
ham
```

I want to find out which items in the **first sheet** that *contains* an exact match from the list in the **second sheet**.

This almost works just this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(good_food;A2)))>0
```

Though TRUE is returned on all items:

```
egg TRUE
bootleggers egg TRUE
egg is good TRUE
eggisgood   TRUE
egg and ham TRUE
eggs and hams   TRUE
bootleggers TRUE
eggshells   TRUE
veggie  TRUE
reggae  TRUE
```

The formula makes a "contains broad match" instead of an "contains exact match". The items "eggisgood", "eggs and hams", "bootleggers", "eggshells", "veggie" and "reggae" should be FALSE.

I am guessting the MATCH-formula might get this to work but I can't figure out how.

**Update:** I don't need to match the items in case sensitive.

Comment: In an [excel-formula], an [EXACT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EXACT-function-243E2BC1-93D6-4FD5-9608-DC3C5B8C046B) is usually used to indicate a case-sensitive match but you have chosen to use [SEARCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) and not [FIND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F). Please clarify.

Comment: I don't think he cares about case sensitivity, more that it's finding partial matches.  So it shouldn't match `egg` in `eggshells` but should match `egg` in `egg is good` because it is a distinct word instead of a partial match.

Comment: @tigeravatar that is correct - I do not care about case sensitivity.

Comment: In that case, your formula is very close, just surround things with the space delimiter, so it can't find partial matches: `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&good_food&" ";" "&A2&" ")))>0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the formula to `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&good_food&" ";" "&A2&" ")))>0` which solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` instead of `search` for exact and specific words to find

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&E16:E18&" "," "&B20&" ")))>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Bracket both the *criteria* and *lookup_range* in a suitable delimiter.

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&B$1&" ", " "&$A2&" "))
```

This is a case-sensitive lookup¹.

[image: exact_wildcard]

---

¹ <sub>The [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) is case sensitive. The [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) is not.</sub>